# Finding the originator of a database query using SQL Azure Data Tools Profiler or related

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-profiler

We've got a rogue process running somewhere that executes queries against a test database we have hosted on Azure SQL.  I'm trying find this process so I can kill it.  There are a number of app servers and development PCs where it could be hiding, and I haven't been able to track it down by looking at processes running on these machines by hand.

I can use The Azure Data Studio Profiler extension to get some Extended Event logging from the database.  From there, I can see the text of queries being run, the Application Name and the ClientProcessID.

Sample data from profiler

[image]

I can't seem to use any of this data to find the host name or ip address of the server where these queries originate.  Can I determine this using the data available in Azure Data Tools Profiler?  Or is there some other way to work backward to find it?  Since this is hosted on Azure, I can't use the Sql Management Studio Profiler, which I think would give me the Hostname right away.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Auditing should provide you the application name, login name and client IP address that executed the query. Please read [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5180/azure-sql-database-auditing-using-blob-storage/) article to enable Auditing and look for the event type BATCH_COMPLETED.

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing ` 
    -State Enabled ` 
    -ResourceGroupName "rgYourResourceGroup" ` 
    -ServerName "yourservername" ` 
    -StorageAccountName "StorageAccountForAuditing" ` 
    -DatabaseName "YourDatabaseName"
```